# How can I optimize my insert function for the cuckoo hash table?

Tags: python, optimization, classes, hash-map

I'm working on class for a hash table where collisions are corrected using cuckoo hashing, I had difficulty writing the insert function, the function is supposed to insert the key if the `h(key)` is available, if not it is supposed to find the shortest "path" for moving other keys in order to find a place for the inserted key, I'm supposed to have maximum `maxdepth` moves.
Is there any way to improve my code?

```
class Cuckoo:
    def __init__(self,funcs,tableSize,maxDepth):
        self.table = [None]*tableSize
        self.funcs = funcs
        self.excess = []
        self.maxDepth = maxDepth
        self.size = tableSize

    def insert(self,key):
        if Cuckoo.find(self, key) != None: # if key exists
            return None
        # key doesn't exist
        min_insert_way = Cuckoo.insert2(self, key, [], 0)
        if min_insert_way[0] == -1: # if we can't commit max 3 replacement
            self.excess.append(key)
            return -1
        # we can commit max 3 replacement
        i = len(min_insert_way) - 1
        orginal_place = self.funcs[min_insert_way[-1]] (key,self.size) # it is the index of key in which it entered
        while ( i>=0 ):
            function_index = min_insert_way[i]
            replaced_element = self.table[self.funcs[function_index](key, self.size)]
            self.table[self.funcs[function_index](key, self.size)] = key # we replace he replaced element with key
            key = replaced_element
            i = i - 1
        return orginal_place



    def insert2(self, key, way, displacements):
        '''
        the function get 4 parameters:
        1. self == the hash table
        2. key
        3. way which is in the begging: way == []
        4. displacements == how many self.funcs have used

        the function return the way in which the insert will be. "way" is list of indexes of the self.funcs in which we do the insert
        for exmple, if way == [2,3], we will put "key" in self.table[self.funcs[3]] instead of "replaced_element".
        then, we will put "replaced_element" in self.table[self.funcs[2]].
        as you can see, the indexes are from the right to the left.
        if we have to use self.excess: way == [-1, X(1), X(1), ... X(max_depth)]
        '''
        if (displacements > self.maxDepth): # if we couldn't find max 3 displacements 
            return [-1]
        for i in range(0, len(self.funcs)):
            if self.table[self.funcs[i](key,self.size)] == None: # if one of the functions gives empty place
                return [i]
        # there is no an empty place
        replaced_element = self.table[self.funcs[0](key,self.size)] # "replaced_element" will be replaced by "key"
        min_way = Cuckoo.insert2(self, replaced_element, way, displacements+1)
        min_way.append(0) # because we have used self.funcs[0]
        for i in range (1,len(self.funcs)):
            replaced_element = self.table[self.funcs[i](key,self.size)] # "replaced_element" will be replaced by "key"
            current_way = Cuckoo.insert2(self, replaced_element, way, displacements+1)
            current_way.append(i) # because we have used h(i)
            if len(current_way) < len(min_way):
                min_way = current_way
        return min_way
```

Comment: You keep saying *"supposed to"* - have you tested it? Does it actually work?

Comment: @jonsharp yes it is working

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, I would suggest using a better name for your helper-function, that describes what it does:

```
def _find_insert_path(...):
```

Note the leading underscore - this is Python convention for "don't call this directly from outside the class". Users should call `insert`, which doesn't have the underscore.

---

Second, you could use exceptions to do handle the case where the insertion depth is exceeded more cleanly. Alter `_find_insert_path` to do:

```
if displacements > self.maxDepth:
    raise KeyError("Maximum insertion path length exceeded.")
```

Which makes `insert` use:

```
try:
     min_insert_way = self._find_insert_path(key, [], 0)
except KeyError:
    self.excess.append(key)
    return -1
...
```

Note the call to `_find_insert_path`; this is an instance method, you don't need to call it on the class and pass the instance `Cuckoo.method(self, ...)` you can call it directly on the instance `self.method(...)`.

---

This:

```
for i in range(0, len(self.funcs)):
    if self.table[self.funcs[i](key,self.size)] == None:
        return [i]
```

Is a pretty awkward way of looping over `self.funcs`, not least because the `start` argument to `range` already defaults to `0`. Instead, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, func in enumerate(self.funcs):
    if self.table[func(key, self.size)] is None:
        return [i]
```

Note that I am testing for the singleton `None` with identity (`is`) *not* equality (`==`) per [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Your loop over `min_insert_way` is similarly awkward; creating and incrementing your own index is usually a sign you're doing something wrong. You could instead use:

```
for function_index in reversed(min_insert_way):
```

---

Fianlly, it seems odd that your helper function returns a list of indices for `self.funcs`. Instead, why not have it return the list of indices within `self.table` to which each item in turn is moved? Then you don't have to call the hash functions at all in `insert`, which becomes much simpler:

```
def insert(self, key):
    if self.find(key):
        return None
    try:
        path = self._find_insert_path(key, [], 0)
    except KeyError:
        self.excess.append(key)
        return -1
    for index in reversed(path):
        key, self.table[index] = self.table[index], key
    return path[-1]
```

Note the parallel assignment of `key` and the value at `self.table[index]`; this uses tuple packing and unpacking to replace three lines of code with one and remove the temporary variable `replaced_element`.

This will also make the loop I mentioned above even simpler; you don't even need `enumerate`:

```
for func in self.funcs:
    i = func(key, self.size)
    if self.table[i] is None:
        return [i]
```

You could also make it neater using default arguments:

```
def _find_insert_path(self, key, path=None, depth=0):
    if path is None:
        path = []
    ...
```

Now the call from `insert` is simply:

```
path = self._find_insert_path(key)
```